# How to use wget with an input file and filenames

Tags: wget, input

i have a text file that contains 10,000 url's with a unique number i want to save the file as.  Each line has a 10 character code, then the URL of the image to retrieve.  How can I make the input file use the first 10 characters as the wget filename?

this is an example of the input file: input.txt

```
x100083590http://image.allmusic.com/13/adg/cov200/drt200/t291/t29123q8m19.jpg
b200149548http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41DoH%2BAWKEL.jpg
z100151855http://image.allmusic.com/13/amg/cov200/dri400/i450/i45035hxdrb.jpg
p400171646http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61cH4n34IhL.jpg
```

`wget -i input.txt` would get the file but not with the preceding unique number.

I want `t29123q8m19.jpg` (the first line) to be saved as `x100083590.jpg`

If there is a better way to write out the input file, say with the URL first, then I can do that too, but I will never know the length of the first field.  Right now the first 10 characters will always be what I want to save the wget image as.

*Edit*  This is being done in a windows environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%l in (Input.txt) do (
    set line=%%l
    wget -O !line:~0,10!.jpg !line:~10!
)
```

Answer (score 6):

In linux.

```
 while read p; do
   newname=${p:0:10} # first 10 chars
   url=${p:10} # remaining chars after the 10th
   wget $url -O $newname.jpg  #get url and output to new filename
 done < input.txt
```

Under windows, we could do:

```
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 for /f %%p in (input.txt) do (
    SET p1=$$p
    SET newname=!p1:~0,10!
    SET url=!p1:~10!
    wget %url% -O %newname%.jpg
 )
```

Comment: Thank you for the Prompt reply Paul.  How would one do it in Windows?

Comment: @Matt Added windows, let me know if you find any bugs

Comment: Here is the error i get upon running this in a batch file:

--2012-11-20 15:19:44--  http://~10/
Resolving ~10... failed: No data record of requested type.
wget: unable to resolve host address `~10'

Comment: @Matt Ok try this.  Stupid windows :)

Comment: Same error. Karan's solution above is almost the same, and is working. I still thank you for your assistance and contribution.

Comment: @Matt Great.  Did you include the first line - setlocal?  Karen's solution is identical, other than doing the substrings on the same line.  I don't want to leave this answer as is if there is a bug, but it works when I use it.

Comment: @Matt Actually, I think I found it - I had the filename quoted.

Comment: Sorry this still isnt working.

C:\Wget\bin>(
SET p1=$$p
 SET newname=!p1:~0,10!
 SET url=!p1:~10!
 wget  -O .jpg
)
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Wget/etc/wgetrc
wgetrc_file_name = C:\Wget\etc\wgetrc
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.

*Edit, Sorry I do not know how to format these comments*

Answer (score 0):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and the `shell` (`cygwin` or `git-bash`):

```
file=/PATH/TO/INPUT_FILE.txt
awk '{print "wget \047" substr($0, 11) "\047 -o " substr($0, 0, 10) ".jpg"}' "$file | sh
```

same, but multi lines version:

```
file=/PATH/TO/INPUT_FILE.txt
awk '
    {
        print "wget \047" substr($0, 11) "\047 -o " substr($0, 0, 10) ".jpg"
    }
' "$file | sh
```